# How to set optional argument for caption in a lstlisting environment

Tags: table-of-contents, listings, captions

Usually, if I set a caption, I use `\caption[short]{long}` to have only a short description in my list of figure for example. But how do I do it with `listings`?

Here a MWE which has a very long caption in the list of listings:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

    \lstlistoflistings

    \clearpage
    \section{A section}
    \begin{lstlisting}[frame=ltrb,caption={This is a very long caption. This is a very long caption. This is a very long caption. This is a very long caption. This is a very long caption. This is a very long caption. This is a very long caption. This is a very long caption. This is a very long caption. This is a very long caption. This is a very long caption.}]
    1=1
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short captions for `lstlisting` environments can be given almost the same way, `\caption={[short caption]long caption}`, see section 4.9 of the `listings` manual.

Please note the `{}` pair to protect for the `[]` argument stuff, which is fragile.

It's perhaps better, to use `{...}` for the long caption as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\lstlistoflistings

\clearpage
\section{A section}
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=ltrb,caption={[short caption]{This is a very long caption. This is a very long caption. This is a very long caption. This is a very long caption. This is a very long caption. This is a very long caption. This is a very long caption. This is a very long caption. This is a very long caption. This is a very long caption. This is a very long caption.}}]
1=1
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]